# While using xxd in Colab Environment, it's executing in bash

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I have a .tflite model that I want to convert to .cc, however, when I do that with xxd, it seems to not be looking in the content/models folder, instead, in the bash file? I know the bash file is where the command is (I believe), but any ideas? I could just be overlooking something.(This is all from the Micro_speech example in tensorflow lite. This specific program is to train a model)

Edit: added better pictures and am now using apt-get for xxd.

Code: [image: code]

Output: [image: output]

Comment: You’re misunderstanding the error message. Of course shell commands are executed by the shell. But it’s not looking for the file “in the bash file”. It’s telling you that the requested file (`models/model.cc`) doesn’t exist in the current location.

Comment: I get that, but it does exist in that location

Comment: It clearly doesn’t. You’re probably not in the `content` folder (you’re in `content/vim`). Incidentally, please don’t post images. Paste the (properly formatted) *text* here.

Comment: I got it, thank you. For some reason it was in /root instead of /content so I just added 
%cd ../content before the xxd command and that fixed it. I would've posted the text, but I wanted to show the file structure as well, even though I could've just done the text then shown the file structure. Oh well, thank you for your help.